# Serializing a text file's new lines missing

Tags: java, perl, xml-rpc

I'm trying to put a local file onto a remote host via XML-RPC Base64 encode/decode. This works perfectly fine for binary files, but when I try to send over the text file, all the line endings are removed. Why's this happening?

On the client side,

```
my $buf;
my $encoded = '';
while (read($FILE, $buf, 60 * 57)) {
   $encoded .= encode_base64($buf);
}
```

To which it then sends over to my Redstone XML-RPC server, which takes it and writes it out:

```
// Create file
   File file = new File(path);
   file.createNewFile();

// Decode the encoded data sent over into bytes
   byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(data.getBytes());

// Write them out to the file
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    os.write(bytes);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
```

Comment: 1. Hope you're using a good text editor (like Notepad++) and not notepad.exe (it doesn't recognize Unix newline chars). 2. Lookup the documentation of your code to see that both encode and decode treat the new-line chars correctly based on your OS combo (sender/receiver).

Comment: Your reading and writing seems correct. Is it that your line endings are only LF and your target system wants CRLF as line ending? Can you check whether the line endings disappear on the client side or server side, i.e. if they are present in the transferred base64 data?

Comment: This is embarassing.. but @thekashyap #1 was spot on. Notepad++ is recognizing the line endings just fine. The server was actually running locally, so I would just take it from one path and go to another path.

Comment: Great.. I take it that the problem is solved? Feel free to post an answer urself and accept it, so it's available to others as answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was opening in Notepad, which wasn't recognizing CRLF endings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the $FILE in binary mode, you need to specify after the open command:

```
open my $FILE, '<', 'the_file_name.extension';
binmode $FILE;

# your code ...
```